# problemas con PHPmailer

Tags: php, phpmailer

Necesito envíar de correos por formulario a través de la librería PHPmailer. Estoy trabajando provisoriamente con localhost con TestMailServer Tool como servidor de correo. Tengo el archivo php.ini correctamente configurado para estos fines. Hice una nueva carpeta donde puse el formulario, el archivo enviar.php y las librerías ocupadas, en este caso solo class.phpmailer.php
Mi ejemplo es un simple formulario con cuatro campos:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="formulario" method="post" action="enviar.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div class="campos">
                <label>Para:</label>
                <input type="email" name="email" required>
            </div>
            <div class="campos">
                <label>Asunto:</label>
                <input type="text" name="asunto">
            </div>
            <div class="campos">
                <label>Mensaje:</label>
                <textarea name="mensaje"></textarea>
            </div>
            <label>Imagen:</label>
            <input type="file" name="adjunto" id="imagen" />
            <input id="submit" type="submit" name="enviar" value="Enviar mail">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

enviar.php

```
<?php
//Librerías para el envío de mail
require "class.phpmailer.php"; 

//obtener campos de formulario
$para = $_POST['email'];
$asunto = $_POST['asunto'];
$mensaje = $_POST['mensaje'];
$archivo = $_FILES['adjunto'];
 
//configurar host
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->IsMail();
$mail->SMTPAuth = false;
$mail->Host = "localhost";
$mail->Port = 25;
 
$mail->From       = "postmaster@localhost"; //Remitente de Correo
$mail->FromName   = "name"; //Nombre del remitente
$mail->AddAddress($para); //Destinatario de Correo
$mail->Subject = $asunto; //Asunto de Correo
$mail->Body = $mensaje; //Mensaje de Correo
$mail->AddAttachment($archivo['tmp_name'], $archivo['name']); //Para adjuntar archivo
$mail->MsgHTML($mensaje);
$mail->IsHTML(true); // Enviar como HTML

//Avisar si fue enviado o no y dirigir al index
if($mail->Send())
{
    echo'<script type="text/javascript">
            alert("Enviado Correctamente");
            window.location="http://localhost:80/PHPmailer/form.html"
         </script>';
}
else{
    echo'<script type="text/javascript">
            alert("NO ENVIADO, intentar de nuevo");
            window.location="http://localhost:80/PHPmailer/form.html"
         </script>';
}
?>
```

Cada vez que ejecuto el código aparece el error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$mail' (T_VARIABLE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\PHPmailer\enviar.php on line 11

Alguien me puede ayudar con esto...

Comment: creo que tu problema se debe a que no estas poniendo un correo valido `$mail->From       = "postmaster@localhost";`

Comment: He intentado con otro correo pero es el mismo error

Comment: Si hago envío con la función mail de php no tengo problemas: https://jsfiddle.net/CMAM/c4yw94dq/

Answer (score 1):

Revisa el path ese es el problema, no encuentra la clase, así que la variable $mail queda vacía ¿cual es la ruta de el archivo "class.smtp.phpmailer"?.

este es mi ejemplo que realice hace poco.

require '../../PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

ya que mi archivo que se llama mailer.php (el que se ejecuta) esta en esta ruta:
C:\xampp\htdocs\birthday\Views\Mail

y el archivo que necesito cargar esta en esta:
C:\xampp\htdocs\birthday\PHPMailer

por eso retrocedo dos carpetas y lo llamo.

espero te sirva, Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Esto lo quería incluir como comentario más que como respuesta. ¿Has visto que invocas al constructor de PHPMailer con argumento (). Por lo que he visto en foros como [este](https://www.sitepoint.com/sending-emails-php-phpmailer/), siempre se asigna sin paréntesis. Un saludo.

Comment: ¿Y por que no lo colocaste como comentarios? O.o

Comment: Es extraño... Cuando lo intenté, stackoverflow me dijo que debía tener 50 puntos o más. Pero, si es que puedes leer este comentario, sabré que no necesito los puntos para comentar. A menos que se requiera que antes haya un comentario previo...
... habiendo dicho lo cuál, y para hacer más productivo este comentario, virtual8870 ¿También has revisado los requerimientos de instalación para esa librería? [enlace] (https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)

Comment: He revisado los requerimientos, pero si logro entender solo se necesita descargar, descomprimir y utilizar la clase class.phpmailer.php en una instalación simple.  `While installing the entire package manually or with composer is simple, convenient and reliable, you may want to include only vital files in your project. At the very least you will need class.phpmailer.php.`

Comment: Ok, lo último que se me ocurre es que quizá tengas algún **caracter que necesite ser "escapado"** (como las comillas simples), dentro de alguna de las variables que asignas a $mail.

Comment: En realidad es un ejemplo que tomé de https://huguidugui.wordpress.com/2014/08/04/enviar-mail-con-phpmailer-desde-localhost/

Comment: Bueno, en el ejemplo que comentas sí se incluye la librería

   **class.smtp.php**

La cuál no viene en el ejemplo que posteas. Sólo digo...

Comment: El ejemplo original utiliza gmail como servidor de correo, que es distinto a localhost. Por eso no creo que sea necesaria esa librería. En todo caso si la incluyo el error sigue apareciendo.